# PHP: Serve pages without .php files in file structure

Tags: php, url, path

I am working on building an internal CMS for clients.  Instead of creating a new php file for each page, I am wondering if there is a way to load up a page based on the URL but not a physical php file in that location.

So, if I visit www.mysite.com/new-page I would like this to just be a reference to my template, content, etc. rather than an actual .php file.

Sorry if I have not explained this correctly, but I am having a hard time explaining it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you're referring to is something like mediawiki (cms used on wikipedia) right? If the article does not already exist (and consequently, the path), then load up a page that will help you create one.

Comment: Sure, this is what is known as routing. Good implementations are found in MVC frameworks like Ruby on Rails, Django, CodeIgnitor, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Basically every URL gets redirected to one PHP page that determines what to do with it. You can use Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

That redirects everything except static content files to index.php. Adjust as required.

If you just want to affect the URL /new-page then try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new-page/ myhandler.php
```

Any URLs starting with "new-page" will be sent to myhandler.php.

Comment: Yes, this does sound like what I am looking for.  But, I don't really want all pages do be served from the index page. I still want URLS like www.mysite.com/page/page2 and www.mysite.com/page-test.  Will the example you gave account for this?

Answer (score 4):

It will normally be the web server that is handling this for you in conjunction with your PHP code. So, for example, if you were using Apache you could use mod_rewrite to do something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And then in your php code you can check `$_GET['page']` to see what page is being called.

So visiting `mysite.com/page/blah` would really access `index.php?page=blah`.

Answer (score 1):

To use mod_rewrite to rewrite the URLs in the one of a PHP page is the solution.
I would rather use a more generic rewrite rule that rewrites any URLs that don't take to a file of a directory existing on the server.

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```