# Multilanguage PHP website URL filename change

Tags: php, url, seo, multilingual

I currently have a multilanguage PHP site on which everything works fine. However, the "file name" does not change when "switching the language."

The URLs are like this:
*www.site.com/br/article.pt.php*
*www.site.com/en/article.en.php*

I want them to be:
*www.site.com/br/**meuartigo**.pt.php*
*www.site.com/en/article.en.php*

How can I do this? I could just do 301 redirects from

*www.site.com/br/article.pt.php*

to

*www.site.com/br/**meuartigo**.pt.php*

but I don't think that's the best way.

Comment: Going so far as to change the filenames is a bit overkill to be honest. Even large scale multi-lingual sites like twitter don't change the url paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal should be

```
www.site.com/br/meuartigo
www.site.com/en/article
```

That's the common format for 'SEO friendly urls'.

You can get a way to do it in the answer to this question:
[Simulate file structure with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144976/simulate-file-structure-with-php/3145037#3145037)