# Rewrite index.php URLs by selected language

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just searched a lot here and googled about this implementation, but I can't figuring out.

I mean: I have a portfolio site (one single page) with 3 languages. Every time I click on a flag (IT, EN, FR) it will load a php file. Inside it there are many translated sentences/words based on choosed languages.

**Question:
The final url is like: `localhost/site/index.php?lang=en` (if you click on English lang).
I want to rewrite it like: `localhost/site/en`

How to write the htaccess file?
**

I just followed this tip --> [Simulate file structure with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144976/simulate-file-structure-with-php/3145037#3145037).

And this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.html$ /$1.php?language=english [L,QSA]
```

I can't figuring out why isn't working.

Other details:
- wamp server
- mod_rewrite activated
- single page site (jquery)
- firefox

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess wants to be something along these lines:

```
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Will direct any requests to files that don't exist to your index.php.

Then in the PHP check the URL and serve up as appropriate:

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uriParts = explode("/", $uri);
$language = end($uriParts);

if ($language == "en) {
....
```

Worth throwing a 404 if it doesn't match an expected language.

Comment: I will try this evening, thank you. Last questions: I'm using WAMP, it may cause problems? I have to pay attention to write my htaccess with WAMP? And where should be created, under root-localhost or my "site" folder?

Comment: any kind of solution doesn't work. Now I suppose is because of WAMP configuration or I miss something in RewriteBase rule. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you got url rewriting enabled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Yep, see "Other details" in my post.
Rewriting system works but the problem is that if I use a simple rule to rewrite `index.php?lang=en` into `en/` or `en`, these URL point to nothing (404).
If I click on this link --> `localhost/mysite/index.php?lang=en` I see `localhost/mysite/en` but it say page not found.
I'm using WAMP, under www folder there is `mysite` folder: this may cause problem with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Your url will be `localhost/site/en.html`